# CorePlot 1.2 - pod install no response

Tags: xcode, core-plot, cocoapods

I just added

```
pod 'CorePlot',         '~> 1.2'
```

to my Podfile, now trying

```
$ pod install
```

> Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
> Updating spec repositories
>
> Cocoapods 0.18.1 is available.
>
> Resolving dependencies for target `default' (iOS 6.0)
> Downloading dependencies
> Installing CorePlot (1.2)

It's getting hanged there with no response.

What can I do ?

Comment: Not sure why this would deserve to be closed. How can someone guess that the program is actually doing things if it's not telling anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This source library is nearly 200 megabytes. It may depend on your internet connection but I imagine this would complete if you gave it enough time.

Comment: Actually I re-checked the filling of the directory, it was more like 500Mo !

Comment: That's crazy, makes sense of why it took so long!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what it is doing try

```
$ pod install --verbose
```