# Cocoapods . Unable to locate the executable `hg` error while pod install, core plot ,

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoapods

```
user$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.21.0.rc1 is available.

Downloading dependencies

Installing CorePlot (1.2)

[!] Unable to locate the executable `hg`


Content of Podfile:
**********************
platform :ios

pod 'CorePlot',      '~> 1.2'
****************************
```

Comment: how about formulating a question?

Comment: Are you a UNIX computer?  What language are you writing?

Comment: Mac OS mountain Lion. Objective-C

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[First result on Google](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/182) (next time you may want to feel lucky)

You need Mercurial to install the CorePlot pod

```
brew install mercurial
```

will solve the issue (assuming you use brew already).
Otherwise just install it from the [Mercurial website](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).

Comment: Gave me error:    brew install mercurial 

Unsatisfied dependency: docutilson console

Homebrew does not provide Python dependencies;
 install with:

  pip install docutils

Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Comment: @neo do what this error is telling you and run `pip install docutils` then run it again.

Comment: Yes, I did. pip install docutils

Gave me another error:-bash: pip: command not found
so, I did sudo easy_install pip. Then ran "pip install docutils". It worked. ran "brew install mercurial", it worked.  Then i ran "pod install" it doesnt give me that "hg" error anymore but now stuck at "Installing CorePlot (1.2)". When i go to coreplot folder inside pod, i foundout there is nothing inside the folder but "Get info" the size keeps on increasing. I left it overnight and in the morning it was zero. terminal still says installing CorePlot (1.2).

Comment: Strange. I tried this morning and it worked. I have to wait for 1 hour. The folder increased more than 515 mb.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164693/coreplot-1-2-pod-install-no-response . This link make me wait and it worked.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Download mercurial manually from this url:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download